# Creating Orchard Module with aspx View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

i have an existing MVC3 Application.
This application uses the Razor view engine AND the aspx Viewengine (for rendering telerik reports).
I want to integrate this MVC Application to Orchard (never used Orchard before).
My question is: 
is this possible? 
can orchard render views with a aspx viewengine?
thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orchard can render aspx, yes, but to make this application work inside of Orchard you'll have to transform it into an Orchard module. if those aspx reports are not MVC but use Webforms postbacks you probably won't be able to use them unless you isolate them into a separate application.

The question to ask would be why do you want to integrate this MVC app to Orchard?

Comment: hi, thanks for respone.
i want to integrate the existing application to orchard because i want to have some cms functionality (authentication, editor, etc.).
Or is there a better way than integrating the application to orchard?

Btw. What do you mean with separate application? A seperate webapplication and render the reports with an iFrame?

Comment: I meant a separate IIS application, not integrated at all.